# I'm using a GSAP animation to pin an image. Works fine on Chrome but Safari messes with the height

Tags: javascript, css, safari, gsap

I have this index of projects that works quite well. I'm using a GSAP ScrollTrigger to pin the image of the projects while the user scrolls through the index.

Here's the live page: https://studio-format.webflow.io/projets

It works very fine on Chrome, but on Safari the "pin-spacer" created by the animation gets a ridiculous height, which makes the page twice its normal height...

Here's the animation's code:

```
function vw(percent) {
            var w = Math.max(document.documentElement.clientWidth, window.innerWidth || 0);
            return (percent * w) / 100;
        }

        let nav = document.querySelector('.navbar').offsetHeight
        let dis = document.querySelector('.display-options').offsetHeight
        let h = nav + dis + vw(1)
        let img = document.querySelector('.index-image-absolute-parent').offsetHeight
        let end_point = h + img

        const tlImg = gsap.timeline({
            scrollTrigger: {
                trigger: ".list-image-container",
                start: "top " + h + "px",
                end: "bottom-=" + vw(10) + "px " + end_point + "px",
                pin: true,
                //markers: true,
            },
            paused: true
        })
        tlImg.play()
```

Does anyone have an idea of a possible workaround?